# Dynamically setting css values inline to divs based on other div height - stick footer with dynamic height

Tags: javascript, css, sticky-footer

I,m using [Ryan Fait's](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) Stick Footer, but I'm trying to achive something dynamically, getting the .footer height and setting inline css to .wrapper and .push so i can use a footer with dynamic height.

I have trying this bit of code, but no sucess:

```
$(function(){
    var footerHeight = $(".footer").height();
    $(".wrapper").css("margin-bottom", -footerHeight);
    $(".push").css("height", footerHeight);
});
```

Some one can enlighten me?

Comment: Actualy I did something wrong and wasn't loading the jQuery correctly and now its working fine. Both answers below are working great as well!

Comment: For those who want to know how its fixed, here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h7Ct7/

Comment: This solution actualy solves the problem for header and footer that uses auto height.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to give it px.

```
$(function(){
    var footerHeight = $(".footer").height();
    $(".wrapper").css("margin-bottom", "-"+footerHeight+"px");
    $(".push").css("height", footerHeight+"px");
});
```

Comment: Actualy I did something wrong in the code and don't load the jQuery properly. TT Tnks, now working fine!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $(function(){
        var footerHeight = parseInt($(".footer").height());
        var actualHeight = parseInt($(".wrapper").css("margin-bottom"))-parseInt(footerHeight);
        $(".wrapper").css("margin-bottom", "-"+actualHeight+"px");
        $(".push").css("height", footerHeight+"px");
    });
```

Sometimes when I want to do this kind of fixes I use a timeout to be sure the page will be fully loaded.

-----EDITED-----

I don't have time to test it but you need to `parseInt` the wrapper CSS. Then you'll have an INTEGER. Also, you need to define if it's PX or %. I´m pretty sure -footerHeight the way you use doesn't work.

Cheers

Comment: Wow nice. That -footerHeight is good to know that can be used that way =)